# AllConsecutives on List<int>

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create an extension method like this

```
public static bool AllConsecutives(this IEnumerable<int> intValues )
```

This method should return true if all items in the list are consecutive (with no gaps)

some test cases

```
(new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}).AllConsecutives() == true
(new List<int>() {3, 7, 4, 5, 6}).AllConsecutives() == true //as it is not sensitive to list order
(new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 7, 6}).AllConsecutives() == false //as the five is missing
```

Comment: yes, and? have you tried something?

Comment: I tried with the aggregate function, but couldn't work out what the seed and accumulator should be.

Comment: Aggregate would work only for an ordered list, imo, since you always visit two consecutive items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int expected = intValues.Min();
foreach(int actual in intValues.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    if (actual != expected++)
       return false;
}

return true;
```

You can also verify, that collection has at least one item, before executing `Min`. Or you can sort items prior to taking min (in this case it will be first one, or will not be any, if collection is empty). Also in this case you will save one iteration for finding minimal value:

```
var sortedValues = intValues.OrderBy(x => x);
int expected = sortedValues.FirstOrDefault();

foreach (int actual in sortedValues)
{
    if (actual != expected++)
        return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: He wanted it to be independent of order. Maybe there's something faster than sorting it first and than apply you algo?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that it should be order-independent

Comment: The list order is not sensitive, therefore `{ 3, 2, 1 }` would fail in your example, but by the examples given, it would be pass.

Comment: Updated example with ordering

Comment: Won't this now always equate to `false` in the first loop iteration? `expected` is the lowest integer, and the first loop asserts `actual` (on the first loop) is not equal to `expected` + 1, which is always true. I think you want to `.Skip(1)` in the `foreach` selection to ignore the first, aka `expected`.

Comment: @phg: no, ordering the list is not necessary - see my solution (that uses an extra hash set though)

Comment: No, it will not fail on first two `examples`, because expected incremented after comparison. But yes, first item could be `Skipped`.

Answer (score 2):

The list is consecutive if it does not contains duplicates and the difference between the max. and min. values is equal to the number of items in the list minus one, so:

```
public static bool AllConsecutives(this IEnumerable<int> intValues) 
{
   int minValue = Int32.MaxValue;
   int maxValue = Int32.MinValue;
   int count = 0;
   HashSet<int> values = new HashSet<int>();
   foreach (int intValue in intValues) {
     if (values.Contains(intValue))         
       return false;
     values.Add(intValue);
     if (intValue > maxValue)
       maxValue = intValue;
     if (intValue < minValue)
       minValue = intValue;
     count++;
   }
   return (count == 0) || (maxValue-minValue+1 == count);
}
```

Comment: Did I overlook something or is `values` always empty?

Comment: @DavidB: thanks...I was losing hope that someone noticed that the sort is not necessary..and is now marked as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Tried and seems to work with the given examples

```
public static bool AllConsecutives(this IEnumerable<int> intValues ) 
{
    var ord = intValues.OrderBy(i => i);
    int curV = ord.Min();
    foreach(int x in ord)
    {
        if(x != curV)
           return false;
        curV++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
if (intValues.Count() <= 1)
                return true;

var ordered = intValues.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();

return (ordered.First() + ordered.Count() - 1) == ordered.Last();
```

Comment: `{2, 3, 4, 7, 6}` passes this.

Comment: OrderBy is deferred until its result is enumerated.  The result is enumerated by the call to First, the call to Count and the call to Last.

Comment: @DavidB - did a bit of reading, and there you go.  Thought that it was sorted on first pass and then not sorted again.  Added a 'ToList' to stop taht.

Answer (score 1):

Error checking and using Linq:

```
 public static class myExtension
{

   public static bool AllConsecutives(this IEnumerable<int> targetList)
   {
      bool result = false;

      if ((targetList != null) && (targetList.Any ()))
      {
         var ordered = targetList.OrderBy (l => l);

         int first = ordered.First ();

         result = ordered.All (item => item == first++);

      }

      return result;

   }

}

// tested with

void Main()
{
 Console.WriteLine ( (new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}).AllConsecutives() ); // true
 Console.WriteLine ( (new List<int>() {3, 7, 4, 5, 6}).AllConsecutives() ); // true //as it is not sensitive to list order
 Console.WriteLine ( (new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 7, 6}).AllConsecutives() ); // false //as the five is missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Sort();
return !list.Skip(1).Where((i, j) => (i != (list[j] + 1))).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that doesn't requires sorting, is to use hashset, and while building the hashset you can hold the min value. With this the run time will be O(n).
This will not take care of duplicate values which you can just add a check while building the hashset and see if the hashset already contains the value.

```
HashSet<int> hash = new HashSet<int>();
int minValue = int.MaxValue;
foreach(int i in list)
{
    if(minValue > i)
        minValue = i;
        hash.Add(i);
}

for(int count = 1; count < list.Count; ++count)
{
    if(!hash.Contains(++minValue))
        return false;

}
return true;
```